# Smart unit tests choosing after commit

Tags: c++, linux, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage

I'm looking for a tool that can solve following problem:

Our complete unit tests suite takes hours to complete. So when programmer commits code, he gets tests result after few hours. What we would like to achieve is to shorten time for finding simple bugs. This could be done by smart selection of few unit tests which would be run just before/right after the commit. Of course we don't want to randomly pick this unit test - we want unit tests that will more likely find a bug.

Idea to solve this problem without additional software:
Make code coverage for each single unit test. Knowing which files are "touched" by which unit test, we can pick this unit test if user changed any of this files.
This solution has obvious disadvantage - we have to manually store and update list of covered files for each unit test.

I wonder, if there is any tool that helps selecting tests to run?
Project uses C++ and works under Linux.

Comment: Why don't just include that information in commit messages? They should already contained # of issue that's being addressed, so it can also base on that.

Comment: If your unit tests are broken into separate independent programs with a good makefile, you can check out the changes without doing a `make clean`, and just run the tests that have to be rebuilt.

Comment: In the .NET world the utility ContinuousTests does this sort of test running

Answer (score 0):

In [*Working Effectively with Legacy Code*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052), Michael Feathers writes that a unit test that takes 10ms is a slow unit test. You must root out the slow tests. Do *not* hack up subset runners based on coverage guesses that will eventually be wrong and bite you.

Keep in mind the distinction between unit tests and integration tests. Unit tests do not touch the filesystem, talk over the network, or communicate with a database: those are integration tests. Yes, integration tests are often easier to write, but that is a strong indication that your software could be factored better—and as a happy coincidence, easier to test.

My suspicion is your integration tests are the ones taking so long. Move those to a separate suite that runs less frequently than on every checkin, say nightly.